# Process a list and output as list

Tags: python, list

I'm quite new to python and have a question about processing a list with a list as result.
Example:

```
list1 = ["vbhg12vbdf42vbsdh24", "dbsh13vdsj24lvk48"] #must become [['12','42','24'], ['13','24','48']]
list2 = (re.findall("\d+", str(list1))) # gives ['12', '42', '24', '13', '24', '48']
```

See comments. Any idea how I can do this?

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you need to specify that your pattern is a regex in your `findall()` function with add `r` at beginning of your pattern, then you need to loop over your list and apply the function on its element,You can use a list comprehension :

```
>>> list1 = ["vbhg12vbdf42vbsdh24", "dbsh13vdsj24lvk48"]
>>> import re
>>> [re.findall(r'\d+',i) for i in list1]
[['12', '42', '24'], ['13', '24', '48']]
```

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
result = []

for x in list1:
    result.append(re.findall("\d+", x))
```

Or, as a list comprehension:

```
result = [re.findall("\d+", x) for x in list1]
```